# Using ArrayFormula for "myfunction" custom formula - Google Sheets

Tags: date, if-statement, google-sheets, lambda, google-sheets-formula

Could you help me with this?

I have one "myfunction" formula which is simple script:

`

```
function myFunction(url)
{
   url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=site:"+url;
      var options = {
     'muteHttpExceptions': true,
     'followRedirects': true
   };
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
   var html     = response.getContentText();
   if (html.match(/Your search -.*- did not match any documents./) ){
     return "Not Indexed";
     }
     else {
     return "Indexed";
     }
}
```

`

And what I want to do is to use ArrayFormula for this funciton but it is not working.

Here's the spreadsheet with example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CYuRd8SlkRVoQjWrFcOzMB387bJU15zLhunylPRIEJY/edit?usp=sharing

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

I've tried this one:

=arrayformula(myfunction(A3))

Comment: what's in A3 ?? share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Done. It's updated in main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=BYROW(A1:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A)), LAMBDA(x, myfunction(x)))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(IF((A1:A="")+ISDATE_STRICT(A1:A)+ISNUMBER(A1:A),,
 BYROW(A1:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A)), LAMBDA(x, myfunction(x)))))
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to add function to not showing value in "B" when "A" is date or number?

Comment: Thanks! Just one more thing. Could you add - when A is empty then skip or not showing anything.